# how to replace regular directory path to java path as string

Tags: java, string, file

I am getting file path from database and I want to open that file. I
 received path as
 'D:\Tasks\Electrolux\Asia\XmlToDB\I008_POK_ServiceOrder_201220162609'
 but java treats ':' and '\' as special characters and giving error
 Invalid Character Constant. My expected output is:  'D:\\Tasks/Electrolux/Asia/XmlToDB/I008_POK_ServiceOrder_201220162609' I used replace as below,

```
public static String getFilePath(String path) {

        str_file_name = path.replace('\\', '/');
        str_file_name = str_file_name.replace(':/', '\\'); //getting error here
        return str_file_name;
    }
```

Comment: Forward slashes work fine, even on Windows: `D:/Tasks/Electrolux/Asia/XmlToDB/I008_POK_ServiceOrder_201220162609`.  You do NOT need to use String.replace() for  a string constant!  Otherwise, consider `String.replaceAll()` to replace ALL slashes!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Your expected output has both forward- and backslashes.  Your immediate error is that `':/'` is two separate characters and cannot be in single quotes (it should be `":/"`) but the overall question is not clear.

Comment: `str_file_name.replace("://", "\\");` should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modify the path before going to pass as a Param to getFilePath(inputPath) see in test program. It may help. Try it Once**

public class FilePath {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String inputPath = "D:\\Tasks\\Electrolux\\Asia\\XmlToDB\\I008_POK_ServiceOrder_201220162609";
    System.out.println(getFilePath(inputPath));

}

public static String getFilePath(String path) {
    path = path.replace("\\", "/");
    // System.out.println(path);
    path = path.replace(":/", ":\\\\");
    // System.out.println(path);
    return path;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `':/'` is a character constant (not a String constant) but contains more than 1 char.
Try `str_file_name.replace(":/", "\\\\");`
(use double quotes)